# Check if UIimageview is populated, then unhide button

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, view

I want to check if uiimageview is populated, then i have a button i want to hide.

I have this code but its not working
It seems to permantaly hide it...

```
    if (imageView.image == nil)
        upload.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: Where's your code to unhide the button?

Comment: i don't think i have a code to hide the button.

Comment: Well there's your problem then. How do you expect it to hide if you aren't telling it to hide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
 if (imageView.image)
    upload.hidden = YES;
 else
    upload.hidden = NO;
```

Comment: Thanks when I get home I'll try it.

Comment: nope if i go to image gallery, and click cancel the button still shows up with nothing in the image view

Comment: Alright i found the problem and your code worked. thanks 1 up

Comment: @Yomo710 Don't forget to accept answers that have helped you.